# Does Windows Portable Devices support TWAIN drivers?

Tags: windows, image, twain, wpd

I am working on an application that must support TWAIN, but additional device support would potentially also be beneficial.  At the moment, I don't anticipate needing anything fancier than the ability to acquire a single image at a time.

I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that WIA supports twain, and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that WPD can be exposed to WIA interfaces.  However, I cannot find any direct documentation on WPD support for TWAIN.

What I am wondering is if I can just implement support for Windows Portable Devices, and "for free" get support for both WIA and TWAIN?  And if so, are there any "gotcha's" in WPD's TWAIN support?

Comment: While TWAIN, WIA, and WPD are all protocols for interacting with hardware devices, TWAIN is more for scanners, and WPD is more for digital cameras and portable digital media players. I suppose it's not a good idea to get TWAIN/WIA support through WPD.

Answer (score 0):

The WIA and WPD compatibility layers are for apps that use TWAIN to access WIA or WPD drivers. An app written in WIA or WPD will be using the respective APIs to access drivers, independent of TWAIN.  In other words, you can think of TWAIN as a layer on top of WIA and WPD, in that order. So you can't actually write an app using WPD to get TWAIN support.

The WPD support for WIA and TWAIN is limited to digital cameras. There is no scanner support for WPD. WIA does support scanners but again it is a layer below TWAIN.